# Classification of string of characters (modified)

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, random-forest, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a problem where I have some 32514 rows of jumbled characters "wewlsfnskfddsl...eredsda" and each row is of length 406 chars. We need to predict which class do they belong to? Here class is 1-12 names of books.

After searching around in the internet I tried the following. Yet, I get a error. Thank you so much.

```
#code
y = ytrain.values
#ytrain = y.ravel()
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=12)

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

X = X.reshape((1,32514,1))


# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(75, input_shape=(32514,1)))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)

# save the model to file
model.save('model.h5')
# save the mapping
dump(mapping, open('mapping.pkl', 'wb'))

#(batch_size, input_dim)
#(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)
```

#### I get the following error:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, 75)                23100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 12)                912       
=================================================================
Total params: 24,012
Trainable params: 24,012
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-503a6273e5d0> in <module>()
      7 
      8 # fit model
----> 9 model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)
     10 
     11 # save the model to file

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1000                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1001                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1002                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1003 
   1004     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1628             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1629             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1630             batch_size=batch_size)
   1631         # Prepare validation data.
   1632         do_validation = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    121                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    122                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 123                             str(data_shape))
    124     return data
    125 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (12,)
```

Comment: This is called sequence classification. So, basically you're trying to do character level sequence classification. LSTMs are great for this

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning & deep learning models for text classification are complex to construct. Here is a guide that can help you get started.

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5782-character-level-convolutional-networks-for-text-classification.pdf

Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, this paper does not use python. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can tackle this problem using lstm.
Long short-term memory (LSTM) units (or blocks) are a building unit for layers of a recurrent neural network (RNN)

These LSTM will help us to capture sequential information and generally used in case where we want to learn the sequential patterns in the data

You can decode this problem using character level LSTM.

In this you have to pass every character of the text in a LSTM cell.and at the last time step you will have a class which is the true label

You can use cross-entropy loss function.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-character-based-neural-language-model-keras/

This will give you complete idea

Comment: Hi Naaviii, thanks for sharing this link. Very nicely detailed. Any suggestions on how I could modify Jason's code in the link. Would my problem still need text generation as this is a multi-class classification problem?

Comment: Hi sm_ , you just have to change the num_classes parameter in that code,as num_classes is 12 in your case and rest is completely fine.Just prepare your data accordingly.The blog's problem is also multi-classification problem,and for that they are using softmax function.Basically softmax will give you probability of every class.

Comment: Hi naavii, I edited his code, but still getting an error. Thanks.